# Borland StarTeam plugin for Eclipse Juno (4.2)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, starteam

I've been looking for the Borland StarTeam plugin for Eclipse Juno (4.2) but am unable to find it.

I tried using the Eclipse 3.4 client from the following update site but it does not work with Juno...

http://altd.borland.com/update/eclipse3.4/site.xml

Does any one know where I can find the StarTeam plugin for Eclipse Juno (4.2)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

for eclipse 4.2 there exist no plugin!
Registered users can download the latest version, for eclipse 3.5 and 3.6, from here http://supportline.microfocus.com/

Georg