# How do I get StarTeam integration w/ MyEclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, myeclipse, starteam

I used top be able to integrate a StarTeam plugin with MyEclipse using this update site URL: http://altd.borland.com/update/eclipse3.6/site.xml

But using newer versions of MyEclipse, this plugin no longer can install, I get this error:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: StarTeam 2009 R2 Eclipse 3.6 Client 11.0.0.97v20111028-1643 (com.borland.starteam_3.6.feature.group 11.0.0.97v20111028-1643)
  Missing requirement: StarTeam 2009 R2 Eclipse 3.6 Client 11.0.0.97v20111028-1643 (com.borland.starteam_3.6.feature.group 11.0.0.97v20111028-1643) requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found

Does anyone have the same problem and found a workaround? I am willing to consider any option... so far my best option seems to be to downgrade Eclipse to an older version where the plugin still works. But I want to see if there's a better alternative out there

Comment: Duplicate question see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697839/borland-starteam-plugin-for-eclipse-juno-4-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the answer by a support rep from the group responsible for the plugin.

Firstly, they no longer offer the plugin via that site URL. You download their plugins from their ftp: ftp://ftp.microfocus.com/download/

and Secondly, they do not yet have a plugin that supports the latest verison of Eclipse, they are still working on it...

Comment: Duplicate question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697839/borland-starteam-plugin-for-eclipse-juno-4-2

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly discourage trying to use StarTeam with Eclipse.  Ever since StarTeam 5.3, Borland has been trying to play catch-up with Eclipse.  In my experience their clients have never worked well with Eclipse even when they did work.  Moves in particular were handled very poorly, and resulted in duplicate files in StarTeam.  Even worse was trying to use IBM WebSphere/RAD with Eclipse and StarTeam/Eclipse plugin, because IBM and Borland always required different versions of Eclipse and were ultimately incompatible.  For a short time there was a time where RAD 6 and StarTeam 2009 (I believe) were both working on the same Eclipse, but the Synchronization was problematic from Eclipse to StarTeam as mentioned.  There was a time when Borland had planned on replatforming the StarTeam Client on top of Eclipse, but not sure what ever happened to that plan.